# How to change ion-nav-bar background colour dynamically

Tags: html, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic app development and basically i have a radio list a user can select options from and for each option i have set up a background colour and what i want it to do is to change the background colour whenever the user selects an option. the problem is that it changes to the initial option but it doesn't change the colour after the initial load although when i inspect the page i can see it has changed the class name.

this is my html

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-{{viewColor}} nav-title-slide-ios7" align-title="center">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-arrow-left-c">
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

and this is how i am assigning the viewColor variable in my js

```
$scope.viewColor = "positive";
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass)

Comment: Try ng-class and save the desired class in the rootScope

Comment: I tried ngClass before posting on here with and without rootScope and it was the same result @GiovaniVercauteren

Answer (score 0):

Try using ionicView.beforeEnter method, set the viewcolor value before the page has finish loaded.

```
$scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function () {
     $scope.viewColor = "positive";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with different solutions (which didn't work) I ended up using ion-header-bar instead of ion-nav-bar and it works! The colour changes dynamically with the users selections. The only downside to it is that I have to create a header for each view and handle the application state myself